# How to copy properties of one class to another in javascript, including methods

Tags: javascript, class, object, copy, extends

I have two classes A and B that work independently of each other, but sometimes I want to create them together, so that the functions in A call the functions in B. This can easily be done by extending B from A and thereby overriding the methods, this however doesn't allow me to create B independently of A.
Instead I want to copy all of the properties and methods. I have tried using `Object.assign` the following example illustrates the problem.

```
class A {
    myFunc() {
        throw 'I have not been created yet'
    }   
}
class B {
    myFunc() {
        console.log(`it's all good now!`)
    }
}

let a = new A();
let b = new B();
Object.assign(a, b)

// explicitly copying the method works
//a.myFunc = b.myFunc;

a.myFunc();
```

**The question is: is there a way to copy all of the methods without doing it explicitly?**

Comment: I'm interested what the usecase for this is?

Comment: I have an object which handles appointments for a customer and all their clients, together with all the logic associated when different events happen (like new appointment created). Then I have another object which generates messages when different events happen and send them to their clients. Together they create a message system. But the message object alone is used to generate preset messages and allows the customers to change their messages. And the logic object is also independent, so that it can be extended by another object eg. for sending packages instead of sending messages.

Comment: It sounds like a better approach may be to export the logic as a utility styled ES6 module and consume it in the 2 other classes. Inheritance will be far more maintainable in the long run than copying methods yourself manually.

Comment: So instead of `myFunc() { console.log(this.name) }` you'd write `myFunc(customer) { console.log(customer.name) }` in a function outside the class. Writing your utility functions in a dedicated file and importing them using ES6 modules (as BlueWater86 has suggested) allows you to keep them bundled together logically without having to have them in the class.

Comment: Yes, I could have the logic object take another "executer object" as a parameter which contains functions that are updated when the logic objects sends out an event. If this is what is being suggested? It is difficult to explain the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate the property names of B's prototype and assign them to the instance of a excluding the constructor in the following way:

```js
class A {
    myFunc() {
        throw 'I have not been created yet'
    }   
}
class B {
    myFunc() {
        console.log(`it's all good now!`)
    }
}


let a = new A();
let b = new B();
//Object.assign(a, b)

for (const prop of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(B.prototype).filter(prop => prop !== "constructor"))
  a[prop] = B.prototype[prop]

// explicitly copying the method works
//a.myFunc = b.myFunc;

a.myFunc();
```